# Representation of number 0-9 in Sanskrit shloka

Tags: scripture, puranas, sanskrit, shloka

Is there any Shloka for number's  from 0-9?

I wanted to know if there is any specific shloka to represent/say these numbers apart from ekam/eka, dwi...etc

Explanation -

I need a verse or a rhyme or a shok from scriptures or puranas in Sanskrit which specifically speaks about any one number between 0 to 9. I am trying to find if there is any language which has a longer description of a number and I think Sanskrit may have it.

For example, it could be something like a verse stating a significance of number 1.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to ask here. Do you want a Sanskrit word or phrase to say "0 through 9" as a series of numbers instead of individual #'s? Or you want synonyms for Sanskrit words: eka, dvi etc? Whatever it is, please add more details to your question. For now I'm voting to close as 'unclear'.

Comment: @sv Added a little details.

Comment: Ok, but how is this related to Hinduism? You can probably ask it on [Area51 - Sanskrit Language](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/98070/sanskrit-language).

Comment: @Techidiot If your question is purely about Sanskrit, then it is off-topic.

Comment: @Techidiot See [discussion](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/748/2995) on meta regarding your question.

Comment: @sv I don't think you can call it as off topic. I am asking about Slokas from the Vedas/Puranas or some other source. And all of which relates to hinduism. If there is no such verse/shloka its fine but closing this one as off topic doesn't look fair.

Comment: @Techidiot Then please update your question saying how it's related to Hinduism. You didn't mention Puranas or other Hindu scripture in your question so right now it looks like a pure Sanskrit question. You can also add `scripture` & `puranas` tags to be clear.

Comment: @Techidiot I don't think u are actually looking for answers like the one that is given..but if u are then there are more slokas like that.

Comment: @Rickross Right. I know there are a lot of that kind. But no, I am not looking for that kind of answer.

Comment: You seem to want Sanskrit ślokas which speak on the properties of single digit numbers, am I right?

Answer (score 4):

There are many hymns attributed to Lord Ganesha. One of them is *Sankatamochana Ganesha Stotram* sung by Sage Nārada. The following is an excerpt from the Nārada Purāṇa .

In the hymn, twelve names of Ganesha are said. They are:

> **प्रथमं** वक्रतुन्डम् च एकदन्तं **द्वितीयकं** | 
>  
>     **तृतीयं** कृष्णपिङ्गाक्षं गजवक्त्रं **चतुर्थकम्**||
>
> Firstly, as the one with the twisted trunk. Secondly, as the one with the single tusk. Thirdly, as the one with the fawn colored eyes. Fourthly, as the one with the elephants mouth,
>
> लंबोदरं **पञ्चमं** च **षष्ठं** विकटमेव च |
>  
>     **सप्तमं** विघ्नराजं च धूम्रवर्णं तथा **अष्टमम्**||
>
> Fifthly, as the pot-bellied one, Sixthly, as the monstrous one, Seventhly, as the king of obstacles, Eighthly, as the smoke colored one.
>
> **नवमं** भालचन्द्रं च **दशमं** तु विनायकं |
>     **एकादशं** गणपतिं **द्वादशम्** तु गजाननं ||
>
> Ninethly, as the moon crested one, Tenthly, as the remover of hindrances, Eleventhly, as the Lord of the hordes, Twelfthly, as the one with the elephants face.

The above said are the twelve names of Lord Ganesha as said by sage Nārada in Nārada purāṇa . Also there is a representation of numbers from 1 to 12.  The number zero (0) is called shoonya(nothing) in sanskrit.

Comment: The rhyme is about Lord Ganesha and is using the numbers as ekam,dwitiyank etc I need a shok which speaks about the number itself like a shlok defining number 1 or two or 3 etc...